# Suppose $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$. Prove that if $A \subset B\subset X$, then $f(A)\subset f(B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to verify that this is a correct, clear and concise solution. I am new to set theory.

> Problem: Suppose $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$. Prove that if $A\subset B\subset X$, then $f(A)\subset f(B)$

Attempt:

1. If $A\subset B\subset X$, then $x_0\in (A,B, X)$.
2. If $f(x_0)=y_0$ $y_0 \in f(A,B,X)$.
3. (Possibly redundant?) Since $y_0 \in Y$ then $f(A,B,X)\in Y$.
4. Therefore $f(A) \subset f(B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh dear just suppose $y\in f(A)$ thus there is $x_0\in A$ such that $y=f(x_o)$ since $A‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\subset‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ B$ you have $x_0\in B$ thus $y=f(x_o)\in f(B)$. although notice that in last inclusion you have to use $\subseteq‎$ instead of $\subset$, for more information ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎see for $f(x)=1$